# SWIFTUI hide navigationBarBackButton for current view in TabView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, tabview

I have a  basic TabView in my XCode project using SwiftUI.
I need to hide `navigationBarBackButton` on 2 views from 3. on the third view (`profileDetail()`) i want the back button to be Shown.

i have tried this, but the back button is hidden when there's at least one `.self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`

```
struct testView: View{
    var body: some View{
        TabView{
            chats().tabItem{
                Text("Chats")
                }.tag(1).self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)


            friendDetail().tabItem{
                Text("Friends")
                }.tag(2).self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)

            profileDetail().tabItem{
                Text("Profile")
            }.tag(3).self.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey — I haven't done exactly what you're doing with TabViews, but I think this would work:

```
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    backButton.title = ""
```

Let me know if I'm understanding the question wrong though.